# Sybase query:save an output to a file

Tags: shell, output, sybase

I´ve created the following script:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    isql -U databasename_dba -P password -b <<EOF!
    select quantity, date from name_table where numer_id="1234" 
    go
    quit
    EOF!
```

Running the script I got the desirable output, see:

```
user@system$ ./EXECUTE_DAILY_4:
```

[image]

But now, how can I save this result that I see in my terminal window in a file? (.csv for example)

I adapted  the  [following](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299978/shell-script-redirect-sql-query-output-to-a-file) to my Sybase query:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat > test.sql <<EOF!

isql -U databasename_dba -P password -b
select quantity, date from name_table where numer_id="1234"
go
quit
EOF!
isql test.sql >result.csv
```

Without success, the above is not working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could effectively do the same thing but within the script itself. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
command=$(
isql -U databasename_dba -P password -b <<EOF!
select quantity, date from name_table where numer_id="1234" 
go
EOF!
)

echo "$command" >> FILE.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple options:

```
isql -U databasename_dba -P password -b <<-EOF > result.csv 2>&1
select quantity, date from name_table where numer_id="1234" 
go
EOF
```

The '> result.csv 2>&1' says to write stdout to the file 'result.csv'; also redirect stderr (fd=2) to stdout (fd=1) (ie, also write stderr to the file 'result.csv'; from here you can do what you want with 'result.csv' (eg, check for errors, parse/process the file as needed, etc).

NOTE: The 'quit' is superfluous as the `isql` session will automatically exit/quit when it has nothing else to do.

If you want to place the query in a *.sql file:

```
echo "select quantity, date from name_table where numer_id='1234'" > test.sql
echo "go" >> test.sql
```

From here you have a couple options for submitting to `isql`:

```
isql -U databasename_dba -P password -b -i test.sql -o result.csv

or

isql -U databasename_dba -P password -b -i test.sql > result.csv 2>&1
```

The '-i test.sql' tells `isql` to take it's input from the file 'test.sql'; the first example uses '-o result.csv' to diredct stdout to 'result.csv' while the second example directs stdout/stderr to 'result.csv'.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Waste a lot of time to find option to write errors "2>&1". Is it possible to add to log some variables also with error (in the first string with concatenation) ? I want to return DB name in the same string with "script failed"

Comment: Hi. Im trying to get the sql output to a csv file. Anyone know how to get the file as a comma delimited file? Currently the output is generated as space delimited.

Below is my code

`$(isql -S$server  -U$user -P$password -D$database <<%%EOF>>RCPGUIProcessChecker.log`
`SET NOCOUNT ON`
`GO`
`DECLARE @nextd DATETIME`
`SELECT @nextbd = nextDate FROM DATETBL`
`EXEC SelectData 'T',Null,@nextd,Null`
`GO > ck4_outfile`
`EXIT`
`EOF)`

Comment: @NisalMalindaLivera you should ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this (a basic solution):

```
./EXECUTE_DAILY_4> FILE.csv
```

I'm open to seeing more suggestions, 
thanks.